# How to use Android's Hardware Scaler for game development

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am familiar with basic app programming in Android, but rather new to Android game development.

I'm trying to find a way to deliver a uniform, performant game experience to Android devices with different screen sizes. During my research I stumbled upon following article:

[Android Developers Blog - Using the Hardware Scaler for Performance and Efficiency](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html)

It suggests setting the SurfaceView's holder to a fixed size:

```
surfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
surfaceView.getHolder().setFixedSize(1280, 720);
```

This method would be quite convenient because then I would not have to care about pixel density and different screen sizes.

My problem is that the article does not explain how to influence the way the Hardware Scaler fits the surface into the view. By default it just stretches the buffer so that the whole buffer gets displayed.

The solution I strive for would be to have some sort of safe area, which always should be displayed, and some margin to fill in the black gaps around the safe area, much like explained in this article:

[Our solution to handle multiple screen sizes in Android](http://blog.gemserk.com/2013/01/22/our-solution-to-handle-multiple-screen-sizes-in-android-part-one/)

How could I achieve such thing with Android's Hardware Scaler?

Comment: One option is to only fix one dimension, i.e. the fixed size is always N x 720, and set the other to maintain the aspect ratio.  I do this in the "Hardware scaler exerciser" in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika); you can see that the squares are always square.  Another option is to fix both dimensions and then configure the GLES viewport to letter/pillar-box to maintain square pixels.  A third option is to fix both dimensions and change the View size and position to get square pixels.  I take it you're looking for the 3rd solution?